# How to detect scrollTo has finished

Tags: javascript, scroll, callback

i would like to ask is there any way to detect if scroll has already finished and then fire a callback? Here's my code:

```
scrollToElementTop (element, offset, smooth, callback) {
    offset = offset.toFixed() || 0
    const positionTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset + offset

    window.scrollTo({ top: positionTop, behavior: smooth })
    callback()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already figured it out, just created promise based function

```
scrollToElementTop (elem, offset) {
    offset = offset || 0

    const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
    const targetPosition = rect.top + window.pageYOffset + offset

    window.scrollTo({
      top: targetPosition,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const scrollHandler = () => {
        if (window.pageYOffset === targetPosition) {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
          resolve()
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    })
  }
```

and then call it like this

```
scrollToElementTop(element, -50).then(() => {
 my code here
})
```

Answer (score -1):

- you can try this when the user stop scrolling for 1 second it's will execute your code

> Example

```
var timer;
window.onscroll = function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        alert("ok")
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea, callback should fire immediately after scroll id done.